# In cartodb, how to automatically update the_geom with new longitude and latitude?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, carto

I am currently posting new table row using the cartodb sql api with the following commands:
u`pdate {table_name} set geom = ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(latitude, longitude),4326)` 
latitude and longitude are taken from numeric columns in my table. However the_geom is not updated, and instead an error is received.

I am aware I can use 'Georeference your dataset' within cartodb to update the the_geom...but I don't want to do this manually whenever I add new coordinates.

Is there a way to automatically update the_geom when I add new new longitude and latitude coordinates?

Comment: I think you can use http://postgis.org/docs/ST_GeomFromGeoJSON.html or http://postgis.org/docs/ST_GeomFromText.html...

Comment: i have doing this: 

update {table_name} set geom = ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(latitude, longitude),4326)

latitude, longitude are number columns in my table, but it gives me an error...

Comment: Could you post your error?

Comment: It simply says syntax error

Comment: If that is exactly the same query you're executing you're missing a parenthesis at the end of the query in order to close st_transform functions.

Comment: ok i corrected it. but now it says undefined rows affected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to use `ST_Transform` because you have already set your map projection with `ST_SetSRID`, so the SQL query would be like this:

```
UPDATE 
  new_dataset
SET 
  the_geom = ST_SetSRID(st_makepoint(longitude, latitude),4326)
```

But if you want to use `ST_Transform`, because you want to visualize your query in Web Mercator or other projection this is the way to do it:

```
SELECT
  ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID(st_makepoint(longitude, latitude),4326),3857) as the_geom_webmercator
FROM 
  new_dataset
```

Comment: In fact you can do it in one step with the [`CDB_LatLng(lat,lon)`](https://carto.com/docs/tips-and-tricks/carto-functions/#basic-functions) function instead of chaining the create and SRID assignment :-)

Comment: I always forget about CARTO functions! :-P